# Ncurses: Refreshing a non-overlapping window refreshes the whole screen. How to avoid this?

Tags: c, unix, ncurses

I am hacking together a ncurses application which uses 5 windows:

- statusbar window - 1 X COLS right at the bottom of the screen.
- titlebar window - 1 X COLS right at the top of the screen.
- 3 content windows - LINES - 2 X COLS, inbetween the statusbar and titlebar.

Note that there are 3 content windows, which entirely overlap each other. I am manually deciding which is to be redrawn. The titlebar and statusbar windows do not overlap any other window.

One use case is for the user to choose a file to upload to a network daemon using a menu in one of the content windows. Upon selecting a file, the statusbar acts as a crude progressbar, drawing some hashes to indicate how far the file has been uploaded.

What this boils down to is using:

- wclear(status);
- mvwprintw(status, ...);
- wrefresh(status);

This works, but for some reason causes the entire screen to be redrawn, causing a horrible flickery mess. Having read the manual, I can not see why this should be the case; as long as the statusbar does not overlap any other windows, redrawing the statusbar should not cause a whole screen redraw?

Am I correct, or have I misunderstood? Is there a way to prevent this?

The code is here:
https://github.com/vext01/hgd/blob/master/nchgdc.c#L812

Note, the code is vastly unfinished and lacks polish =)

My ncurses implementation is that of OpenBSD.

Comment: Can you write a very short stand alone program that demonstrates the behaviour?  What terminal are you running this in?  Be aware that some terminals may have limited capabilities and as a result require the entire screen to be redrawn where others may not.

Comment: In doing so I see the offender. A wclear() seems to cause the whole screen to update! Without it, I am flicker free. Why is this? https://gist.github.com/1605660

Answer (score 0):

From the wclear man page:

> The  clear and wclear routines are like erase and werase, but they also
>          call clearok, so that the screen is cleared completely on the next call
>          to wrefresh for that window and repainted from scratch.